# Error de convertir un Datetime a string

Tags: c#, asp.net

Me pueden ayudar tengo un error estoy intentando hacer una busqueda por medio de un filtro en el cual al momento de buscar una fecha me va a mostrar los datos pero tengo un error en el cual me dice que tengo que no puedo convertir de datetime a string estoy usando asp.net en c# y sql server

```
 public ActionResult Buscador(DateTime Fecha)
        {
            var busqueda = from s in db.Clientes select s;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Fecha))
            {
                busqueda = busqueda.Where(s => s.Fecha.Contains(Fecha)
                                       );
            }
            return View(busqueda.ToList());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu fecha parece ser un string, te faltaria parsear el Datetime

```
    public ActionResult Buscador(DateTime Fecha)
    {
        var busqueda = from s in db.Clientes select s;

        if (Fecha != null)
        {
            busqueda = busqueda.Where(s => s.Fecha.Contains(Fecha))
                                   );
        }
        return View(busqueda.ToList());
    }
```

Edite la respuesta ya que segun el comentario, me di cuenta de que estabas usando la libreria de String para verificar un tipo de dato Datetime.

Comment: aqui es donde radica el problema String.IsNullOrEmpty(Fecha) falta Fecha?.ToString().

Comment: esque al momento que hago eso me dice que fecha no contiene ningun Contains

Comment: y estas segura que estas pasando la info?

Comment: Si esque el problema que solo tengo es de la fecha.Contains es la unica falla que me esta dando

Comment: Tu dato fecha en el listado de qué tipo es? Probaste con Fecha. Equals(fecha)

Comment: a ya se lo puse ya no me dio error deja lo calo gracias